# jquery log span attribute in a div container to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to log the marked `<span>` attributes in the picture below.

```
$("#user-lists div.list.room").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).children().text);
});
```

[image]

How can I improve my code example?

Comment: Sorry, this question is far from clear. Please edit the question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: This is a poor question, I can see you're new but you're going to have to give some more information.  For example, which attributes? What do you mean you want to edit the span in the subdivs?  You edit or let the user edit?  The first one is easy, open notepad and edit the html page, the second one will need inputs and other user-interface elements perhaps too like a button to confirm the edit etc.

Comment: theres a screenshot below

Comment: thank you that was the problem

Comment: is it able that it doesnt do everything in 1 console log?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LYN92/)**</kbd>

```
console.log($('.name').text());
```

Comment: is it able that it doesnt do everything in 1 console log?